# get newest duplicated records ids from 2 tables sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables:

**Table 1**

```
id | column_1 | column_2 | parent_id | added_at
-------------------------------------------------
1  | 0        |0          | 1        | Date 1
2  | 0        |0          | 1        | Date 2
3  | 1        |0          | 1        | Date 3
4  | 1        |0          | 1        | Date 4
```

**Table 2**

```
id | column_1 | column_2 | parent_id | added_at
-------------------------------------------------
1  | 0        |0          | 1        | Date 5
2  | 0        |0          | 1        | Date 6
3  | 1        |0          | 1        | Date 7
4  | 1        |0          | 1        | Date 8
```

The result should be for this particular case:

`[[2], [4], [1], [2], [3], [4]]`

we should get the newest ids when column_1 and column_2 are duplicated in both tables.

i've been trying with something like this one:

```
 SELECT x.id
   FROM (
    SELECT t1.column_1, t1.column_2, t1.parent_id, t1.id
    FROM table_1 t1

    UNION

    SELECT t2.column_1, t2.column_2, t2.parent_id, t2.id
    FROM table_2 t2
   ) x
 GROUP BY x.position_x, x.position_y, x.parent_id
```

But i'm getting `[[1], [3]]`

Expected result with ids from both tables:

`[[2], [4], [1], [2], [3], [4]]`

`2, 4` are ids from the first table and `1, 2, 3, 4` are ids from the second table

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? Please only use the tag you're using

Comment: I'm lost.  How do your return six results if you want only the *newest* ones?  What do the numbers mean?  Your question is even more obscure because the ids are the same in both tables and your sample code doesn't match the data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @GordonLinoff i want to get the duplicated records where column_1 and column_2 have the same values

Comment: can you explain better what is the expected result ?   [[2] //is it an id from table1 or table2?, [4]//same question, [1], [2], [3], [4]]

Comment: @Shaolin i've added the expected result details

Comment: @1pct thank you, can you explain why 2,4 from 1st table are selected ? because both tables have the same content except the date.

Comment: yup because id 1 of the first table has `column_1: 0` and `column_2: 0` and i don't want more repeated values with these columns for `table_1/table_2` Same for id 3 of the first table. i don't want to have more records with `column_1: 1` and `column_2: 0` for any table

I want to have only one record with `column_1` and `column_2` with the same values. It does not matter if is in table_1 or table_2, i need the newest ids to remove the duplicated records later

Comment: One thing I still don't understand is why all results from table 2 are kept ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this is what you want :

```
SELECT MAX(id) as last_id
FROM table_1
GROUP BY column_1, column_2
UNION
SELECT id
FROM table_2
```